# Finding whether latlong location belongs to a Google Maps polygon in PHP with REST API

Tags: php, android, rest, google-maps, geolocation

Finding whether latlong location belongs to a Google maps polygon in PHP.

my problem is I have set of latlong in database , they are forming a polygon on Google maps  , I want to test whether a latlong supplied by my client/some resource belongs inside that polygon or not ,I do not use [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) 
solution because it is interactive solution , that means we have click on the map and then it will give he feedback as green or red circle

Answer (score 0):

```
                        <script>
                  // This example requires the Geometry library. Include the libraries=geometry
                  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
                  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">

                  function initMap() {


                    // var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    //   center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.269},
                    //   zoom: 5,
                    // });
            console.log('step1');
            /*
                    var triangleCoords = [
                      {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19},
                      {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
                      {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
                    ];
            */
            var triangleCoords = "[{"lat":-34.875334116012,"lng":138.52427244186},{"lat":-34.95528700453,"lng":138.53869199753},{"lat":-34.958100827485,"lng":138.69730710983},{"lat":-34.880403863759,"lng":138.71653318405}]"; 

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.933448, 138.595618);



            console.log('step2');
                 var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: triangleCoords});


            console.log('step3');



                      var resultColor =
                          google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point , bermudaTriangle) ?
                          'red' :
                          'green';

            console.log('step4');

                          console.log(resultColor);





                  }
                </script>



                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAeAQfn6BM5p8FhFde5yq7fm7V-DHQL0RQ&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"
                     async defer></script>
```